# Looping through REST API with pagination, getting data and sending to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm new to Apache Kafka building some applications and i get stuck dealing with a specific problem.

[image: Structure]

I'll try my best do explain my use case.

I have an **external application**, that is a kind of ticket manager and would like to pull data from them. They have a paginated REST API where i can get ticket data by a client. I would like to loop through this API 'till the last page and send it to Kafka, where my Sink Connectors would send them to three DBs.

Q) My best option is to create some kind of python script to get data and /POST/ them to Kafka REST Proxy API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have really any good option here.

Pages imply ordering; if you have N pages and attempt to send N requests, then your producer request could fail and retry any one of them, causing loss of information and random order

Two options to fix that

- send "page count" and "current page" along with each message and reshuffle data at some downstream system
- don't produce any message until you iterate all pages, keeping in mind that Kafka has a maximum request size

Problem with either approach - what happens if another page is added to the API while you're producing or writing to the database? Or if they change? How will you detect which pages you might need to request again/overwrite?

> POST them to Kafka REST Proxy API?

If the REST Proxy is the only way you're able to get data into the cluster, then sure, but it'll be less performant than a producer